# WinRT 8.1 Phone - ListView reordering

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to create a reorderable ListView in a Windows Phone 8.1 app created using WinRT.
The XAML is the following (it binds to an ObservableDictionary in the codebehind):

```
<Grid Margin="24">
        <ListView x:Name="MainListView" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Padding="24" Margin="16" Background="CadetBlue">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

The ListView does nothing when I try to reorder the items (it looks like the "reordering mode" is not activated).

When I run this sample in Windows 8.1 (the XAML is shared) it works as expected. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems.aspx) Windows Phone 8.1 should be supported.

Is this functionality supported on the phone (and the documentation wrong) or do I need to do something special for the phone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For WP you need to set [ListViewBase.ReorderMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/elibrary/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.reordermode.aspx)

This is what works for me - no idea which properties are really necessary; ReorderMode is set in code behind:

```
<ListView x:Name="fooListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding barlist, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectionMode="None"                
          AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" />
```

The ListViewBase.Reorder property is available *only* for Windows Phone, so if you have the XAML in a Shared part of a universal app, you need to set it using conditional compile like so:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            MainListView.ReorderMode =  ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
#endif
```

Comment: This is a good catch, although it's weird that the ReorderMode is not set automatically when dragging is started

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the property `CanReorderItems` is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1.

(I tried a simple example, and it does not work, and I could not find any combination that made it work as it does on Windows 8.1.)