# Delete and reorder ListViewItems of a ListView in Windows 10 Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Currently, I am working on a Windows 10 Universal Apps. I would like to let user to manipulate a ListView, such as delete and reorder items. I found some solutions online,such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875849/winrt-8-1-phone-listview-reordering) but the solutions only work on Desktop App.

```
CanDragItems = "True" 
IsSwipeEnabled = "True"
ReorderMode = “Enabled”
```

However, we would like to seek for a solution on mobile phone too.At least we can let the user to delete some items by themselves.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to handle the list or collection you bind to the listview at code behind. That will be the most reliable way.

Take the reorder as example: if we use linq to query your backend source with "order by" and re-bind it onto the listview, you get it reordered.

Comment: Thanks Alan. However, we want to let the users to edit the ListView by themselves. For example, they can drag and draw an item to some place, then we can rebind the listview at code behind. The drag and draw do not work in mobile phone emulator but work fine in desktop universal app.

Answer (score 0):

For Phone, you have to use the ListViewReorderMode enumeration.  For example:

`ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled`

and

`ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Disabled`.

These are from the Code-Behind.